# Only allow traffic on port 80 for only 1 IP address

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, firewall

We are currently going through a DDOS attack, and have outsourced DDOS mitigation to BlockDOS.net. Problem is they want me to block all port 80/443 traffic except from their IP address.

If I block all in the Windows Firewall Advanced Security, I can't override that with an allow.

How do I block everything but their IP for that one local IP address on Ports 80 and 443?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows firewall defaults to blocking inbound traffic. So remove all allow rules for inbound traffic on ports 80 and 443, then recreate a rule allowing traffic for the IP address you need.

Also, look into getting yourself a hardware firewall. A little part of me dies inside every time I see somebody making their server directly accessible on the internet without a firewall.

Comment: That is what I had thought... I had to then find the rule that was leaving the ports open. Thanks!